# Electron, how open app from tray instead start a new one?

Tags: electron

How to create a single instance of an Electron app? If it's already running in the tray and user starts it again, how to open the running app from tray instead of starting a new one?

Comment: Can you share your main js file? Where you have all your electron settings? I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app.makeSingleInstance()`, to make sure the user does not open multiple instances of electron. Once you share your code I will make an edit to show you how to properly implement it.

```js
var shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance(function(commandLine, workingDirectory) {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
  if (myWindow) {
    if (myWindow.isMinimized()) myWindow.restore();
    myWindow.focus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

thank you!
I found this in docs, https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock:

```
const { app } = require('electron')
let myWindow = null

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to start a second instance, focus our window.
    if (myWindow) {
      if (myWindow.isMinimized()) myWindow.restore()
      myWindow.focus()
    }
  })

  // Create myWindow, load the rest of the application, etc.
  app.on('ready', () => {
  })
}
```